# All my objects became non-selectable

Tags: selection-tools, outliner

All the objects in my scene (around 2'000) have the selection feature disabled all of a sudden (v.2.78):

[image]

I can drag the mouse down to reselect them, but the computer lags, and a lot of them don't get highlighted when I do this.

I looked at [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/60544/how-to-toggle-selection) and [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6786/how-to-toggle-visibible-selectable-renderable-for-multiple-objects), but I cannot find out how to make the scripts work.

Is there a quick and dirty way to make all the objects in the scene selectable again?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One option is to use shortcuts in the [Outliner](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/outliner.html) editor - <kbd>V</kbd> for visibility of the objects, <kbd>S</kbd> - for selectability and <kbd>R</kbd> for renderability. Note that mouse has to be over the Outliner editor while using the shortcuts.

1. Open the Outliner. You need to point to Blender which objects' settings you want to edit. As they are unselectable, press <kbd>A</kbd> which will create blue overlay over the objects and will select them for the Outliner actions.
2. Press the shortcut for desired operation, in the case of the question - <kbd>S</kbd> for selectability.

[image: screenshot-Outliner-the-magician]

Note that this is toggle, so it will invert current state of the adjacent property; if object-A was unselectable and object-B was selectable, objectA will become selectable and objectB the other way around.

Comment: The S shortcut toggles selection on or off even if the object is deselected when I try this. If I have all the even object numbers selected and the odd numbers not selected, it will switch. I am trying to select all or deselect all.

Comment: @MicroMachine if the property is toggled then the object is selected (in Outliner). Toggling is indeed the downside of this method which is mentioned in the last paragraph of the answer; meanwhile the addon from the [answer you linked](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/6898/33624) works [just perfectly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIpfC.gif) thanks to Pink vertex.

Answer (score 0):

While the addon in the [first linked answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/60556/935) works, it has a main flaw, it either toggles or sets the selectability of the *selected objects*, so you can easily disable the selectability but you can't enable it unless you can select the object/s to start with.

The [other answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/6898/935) works as expected, which is it *toggles* every object that is selected in the outliner. While selecting all is easy enough, that may include objects you don't want to toggle. This is really just the same result as the answer by WKG which has always been in blender.

For a simple brute force solution that just enables the three options shown in the outliner for every object -

```
import bpy

for o in bpy.data.objects:
    o.hide_select = False
    o.hide_render = False
    o.hide = False
```

You can easily adjust that to disable them again or just alter one of the options. You could change `bpy.data.objects` to `bpy.context.selected_objects` if you wanted to disable a selection of objects.