# Disable selection shortcut - on viewport

Tags: selection-tools, shortcut

Any way to set a shortcut to disable an object selection on viewport? Instead to go to the outliner and set on by one?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you can select multiple objects in the outliner, right click and and toggle selectability https://i.stack.imgur.com/0UO80.gif

Comment: Thanks, @cegaton. But I'd like to do this in the viewport, not in the outliner. To create a shortcut or use an existing shortcut to do it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to toggle selection?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/60544/how-to-toggle-selection)

Comment: Also related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6786/how-to-toggle-visibible-selectable-renderable-for-multiple-objects