# How do I disable 'Restrict viewport selection' for multiple objects?

Tags: objects, 3d-view, outliner

I accidentally turned on 'Restrict viewport selection' for each object. How do I turn them all back off without having to click the objects one by one?

[image]

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/60544/how-to-toggle-selection and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6786/how-to-toggle-visibible-selectable-renderable-for-multiple-objects. There isn't as fast way as renderability / selectability, but there's a way in Outliner, border select datablocks and press S

Comment: Can try shift click and drag.